# Asynchronous Bitbang mode vs Synchronous Bitbang mode

Tags: bit-bang

I am still newbie in the field of electronic, and I have to write program to flash LED light as well as receive light data via photodiode. I am currently using FT2232H mini module. I have trouble understanding what an Asynchronous Bitbang mode is and how is it different from Synchronous Bitbang mode. I tried to send repeating 101010 on send an Asynchronous Bitbang mode, but the receiver sometime read as 11011011 and sometime as 00100100 (notice double 1 or double 0). On the other hand, I tried Synchronous mode, but all I got is random bits. What would be the right approach to this situation? What mode should I use for receiving a predefined data rate (e.g. sender sent at constant 30kbit/s)

reference:http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_232R-01_Bit_Bang_Mode_Available_For_FT232R_and_Ft245R.pdf

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram for how you are wiring this up?  How are you measuring that you receive 11011011 or 00100100?

Comment: I don't have a circuit diagram, I use a receiver that convert current from photodiode to voltage. I measure this using the same FTDI microcontroller. Currently I wired a function generator to the LED, and setup such that it generates 1010 at certain frequency. It seems my problem is understanding the baud rate vs bit rate, because I tried 20Hz flashing rate and 8000 baudrate. I got 101010 with certain interval of 1111 (I believe this is because reading rate is not the same as the actual data rate). I thought baudrate and bitrate should be the same under LED flashing..